# Custom Split Activity is getting a 403 (Forbidden) error every time

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I need to make an API call to check whether a particular user is excluded or not directly within Journey Builder. In this case, I'm implementing a Custom Split Activity.

My config.json as follows:

```
{
"workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
"metaData": {
    "icon": "ABC.com/assets/logo-noname.6481e0b2155ed5945f02.svg",
    "category": "customer"
},
"type": "RestDecision",
"lang": {
    "en-US": {
        "name": "NSER Check [DEV] ",
        "description": "NSER Check"
    }
},
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments": [
            {
                "SubscriberKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"
            }
        ],
        "outArguments": [
            {
                "selfExcluded": "Boolean"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://ABC.com/api/account/v1/issalesforcenserselfexcluded",
        "timeout": 10000,
        "retryCount": 3,
        "retryDelay": 1000,
        "concurrentRequests": 5
    }
},
"outcomes": [
    {
        "arguments": {
            "branchResult": "true",
            "some argument": "NSER Success"
        }
    },
    {
        "arguments": {
            "branchResult": "false",
            "some argument": "NSER Error "
        }
    }
],
"configurationArguments": {
    "publish": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=publish&env=dev"
    },
    "validate": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=validate&env=dev"
    },
    "stop": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=stop&env=dev"
    },
    "save": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=save&env=dev"
    },
    "testPublish": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=testPublish&env=dev"
    },
    "testSave": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=testSave&env=dev"
    },
    "testStop": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=testStop&env=dev"
    },
    "testUnpublish": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=testUnpublish&env=dev"
    },
    "testValidate": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=testValidate&env=dev"
    },
    "unpublish": {
        "url": "ABC.com?lifecycle=unpublish&env=dev"
    }
},
"userInterfaces": {
    "configModal": {
        "url": "ABC.com/"
    },
    "configurationSupportsReadOnlyMode": true,
    "configInspector": {
        "size": "scm-lg",
        "emptyIframe": true
    }
},
"schema": {
    "arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
            ],
            "outArguments": [

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

But every time I execute the journey, I get the following error in the journey health.

```
Failed - 2023-07-19 11:36 PM
Error - The REST response does not contain a required outArgument (selfExcluded).
Error - Duration: 119 ms, Status Code: 403, Status: Forbidden, Response Size: 4520 bytes
Error - Can't parse returned data required for the REST activity.
```

The API is working fine with Postman using the same parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the response from postman?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the response must be a 200OK with a body consisting on a JSON object containing at least the branchResult: {branchResult: '<KEY FOR PATH 1>'}

Comment: Hi @SebOD, thanks for your response. the response is {
{
  "selfExcluded": false
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the response as [@SebOB](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/28927/sebob) mentioned. Expected response was `{branchResult: <KEY FOR PATH 1> [true/false] }`

Comment: Next time, ask me to post the comment as the response so I can get some points ;)

Comment: ahh really sorry about that, definitely I'll do the same, thank you very much for your feedback on this.